# How to upgrade STS 3.6.3 for Eclipse to use the latest Spring Framework

Tags: eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite

It is quite interesting that the latest Spring Tool Suite for Eclipse continues to use the outdated Spring Framework 3.1.1. Is it possible to migrate the STS to the latest Spring Framework? If so, what are the steps for doing the migration?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think STS 3.6.3 uses the outdated Spring version 3.1.1? STS supports the latest versions of Spring and you can use whatever version of Spring you want to in your projects in STS.

If you are referring to some of the template projects, they might use older versions of Spring and are not being updated anymore. The preferred way to create Spring projects is to use the Spring Starter wizard or the wizard to import the Spring Guides, they usually use the latest versions of Spring and are based on Spring Boot - which is also supported in STS.

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: I have heard about using the "New Spring Wizard" to create project for the latest spring mvc + spring boot

Comment: Thanks Martin. I have heard about using the "New Spring Wizard" or the "Spring Starter Wizard" to create project for Spring 4.1 based on Spring Boot. I cannot locate either of those wizards in my IDE. I am using STS 3.6.3 in Eclipse Luna. How can I locate them?

Comment: Sounds like your installation isn't complete or some parts are missing. Can you download STS from http://spring.io/tools/sts/all and give that a try? If you want to analyze in more depth why those components are missing in your installation of the STS components in Eclipse Luna, we would need to dive a bit deeper (open the OSGi Host Console, typing in "ss", press enter, post the result somewhere). Hope that helps!